# Should I install ruby as root or user?

Tags: ubuntu, ruby

I'm not sure which option to take. I'm installing ruby on VPS.

My options:

1. Install ruby from ubuntu repository
2. Install RVM
3. Install RVM as user
4. Install RVM as root

I've 1 user VPS, that handles apache/php/python projects. I'm learning ruby, so I will add ruby system tools (I made plugin for munin) and rails apps obviously.

I would like to make informed decision, and keep my VPS (production) in shape and correctly configured.

I could go with either choice and end up with working system. But I would like to make informed decision and learn a thing or two about system administration.

Thanks!.

Comment: It is always a good idea to install from the repository unless the repository doesn't have what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends on your requirements.

Do you have apps that require different versions of ruby?  Will you have a need to run different ruby version in the future?  If, so then you will probably want to use RVM.  I would install it as root as each user you must add to the RVM group and I believe even if installed as root, each user gets their own folder.

If you want simplicity and only plan on running one version of Ruby then, go with the repository.  In my opinion, that route is much easier.  You can do it with RVM and you'll be just fine, but it may be a little harder and more time-consuming.